# Ttrigger extra parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to the jQuery manual you can send extra parameters (as an array) when calling a trigger. I am using this at the moment:

```
$('#page0').trigger('click', [true]);
```

How would I pick up whether the paramter has come through or not when using this?

```
$('ul.pages li a').click(function() {
  // Do stuff if true has been passed as an extra parameter
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul.pages li a').click(function(event, param) {
  if (param) {
    // Do stuff if true has been passed as an extra parameter
  }
});
```

If the click event was triggered normally, `param` will be undefined and body of the `if` statement won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the arguments array without specifying a permanent function prototype (arguments[0] is the event itself):

```
$('.post-text').click(function() {
    if(arguments[1]===true) {
        // do something
    }
});

$('.post-text').trigger('click',[true]);
```